# Like * does not capture Is Null values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access Query that filters a table in my database using

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] & "*"
```

which grabs filtered items if that filter is selected, or returns everything if that filter is unselected. However, it misses Null values. If the filter is unselected, the string becomes

```
Like **
```

which does not capture Null values.

How can I capture these values in the way I describe?

Comment: Does `OR IS NULL` work in Access?

Comment: It does, but then when there is a filter selected, the Null values show up with the filter. The Access string would be "Like "*Filter*" Or Is Null" which returns Null values with the filtered values, which is not what I want. I would like the Null values to only show when there is no filter selected.

Comment: Then you'd need something like, `(Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] & "*") or (my_filter_is_empty AND MyField IS NULL)`. I'm just not sure how to express "my_filter_is_empty" in Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by or'ing the null check so it returns data for both conditions -->

```
(Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] & "*" OR MyField IS NULL)
```

Also, you should be able to check the UI is absent a value-->

```
 (Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] & "*" OR [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] = "" )
```

Comment: See the comment on the main post. If I do this, Null values will always show, whether the filter is applied or not. Is there a way to do it so that Null values only show when the filter is unselected?

Comment: Then include the UI portion in your check so that you check that it contains a value and if not return true. OR [Filter]=No Value.

Comment: Very well, I think the UI check is the way to go, didn't realize you could do that. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

The above two answers are correct, but to provide some added context NULL cannot be compared to anything.  It's not 'not 5', 'not like "**", 'not like "*foo*"', not 'Date < #12/31/0000 BC#', not False, you get the idea.   The only way to pick it off is to do as the above experts state, IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Access Query criteria, you can **use an `OR` as well**:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] & "*" Or Is Null
```

...to have Null *not* return, then use:

```
Is Not Null
```

...or,

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Reports]![Filter] & "*" And Is Not Null
```

Comment: See the comment on the main post. If I do this, Null values will always show, whether the filter is applied or not. Is there a way to do it so that Null values only show when the filter is unselected?

Comment: @squeegene - without a sample of your data and expected result, I can't  get any more clear than that but the answer is a combination therein.

Comment: Thank you for your help, ashlee! I will certainly try these options